# jquery + fadein callback

Tags: jquery

I have written the following code to fadeout a DIV, then load a new DIV and then fadein the same DIV with the new content:

```
    $('div#contentwrapper').fadeout('slow',
        function() {
            $('div#contentwrapper').load('scripts/php/home.php',
            function() {
                $('div#contentwrapper').fadein('slow');
            });
    });
```

However it never fades out/in the page.
I know the .load() is working as I've tested it on its own.
Can anyone see any mistakes in this code?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`. Notice the caps.

Here's a demo with caps: http://jsfiddle.net/vVwF8/

Here's the error I get when I don't use caps:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fadeout'
```